# preview uploaded image file using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

In an express.js application, I have a form with some fields and on of them is an upload image field.

When the user browse his images files and choose one, I want to display this file in a "preview block" before the form submission.

I thought to these actions :

1. Click on the browse button
2. Choose a file
3. File has been selected =>  upload it, rename it, resize it, crop it and store it in the `/tmp` directory
4. Display the new file in the preview block
5. Form validation => move the renamed file in the appropriate app directory

I'm searching for the best way to achieve this process.

Comment: you want these operations to be done on client or server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps to solve this problem.

1. Use input type **file** in HTML file.

   ```
   <input id="upload_images" type="file" multiple="multiple">
   ```
2. Add event listener to the change event of the input type file.

   ```
   if(document.addEventListener) {
       document.getElementById("upload_images").addEventListener("change", function(e){
           uploadImages(e);
       });
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById("upload_images").attachEvent("onchange", function(e){
           uploadImages(e);
       });
   }
   ```
3. When the file is selected by the user, create a form data and using ajax send it to the server (Mutipart Data).

   ```
   function uploadImages(e) {
       var uploadedFiles = e.target.files;
       var xhrObj = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhrObj.open('POST', "<<your node>>/<<request URI>>", true);
       xhrObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
           if(this.readyState == this.DONE) {
               if(this.status != 200) {
                   // Show Error
               }
               else {
                   var returnedResponse = xhrObj.responseText;
                   if(returnedResponse == 'success') { // check your returned data like I was returning "success"
                       // Success - Do the tasks
                   }
               }
           }
       };
       var requestFormData = new FormData();
       for(var i=0; i<uploadedFiles.length; i++) {
           requestFormData.append('data', uploadedFiles[i]);
       }
       xhrObj.send(requestFormData);
   }
   ```
4. On server(nodejs) use **formidable** to receive the file/files uploaded and store it wherever you want.

   ```
   // require formidable
   // require imagemagick
   function processUploadImages(req, res) {
       var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
       form.uploadDir = __dirname+'/uploaded_images/;
       form.maxFieldsSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024;
       form.keepExtensions = true;
       form.onPart = function(part) {
           form.handlePart(part);
       }
       form.on('file', function(name, file) {
           // Handle file data like:
           // file.path
           // file.name
       });
       form.on('end', function() {
           //show complete
       });
       form.parse(req, function(error, fields, files) {
           // create thumbnail images
           // return response
       });    
   }
   ```
5. On server(nodejs) create a thumbnail image using **imagemagick** and store it in a folder which can be located anywhere.
6. Send the saved (image and thumbnail) links back in the response.
7. Create a image tags and use these links in the src tag.

Comment: OK, I understand the process. I never used formidable. Do you have a working example ? Also in my research, I found that http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput maybe it can be a part of the trick

Comment: Yes I have done that but if it not urgent, do it on your own, if any problem I will give you the working example/code.  :)

Comment: TY. Yes, if possible, can you show me how you achieved steps 2 & 3 ? For other it's ok. I wrote my own with listeners & sockets, it works great but it's very ugly ...

Comment: @ceadreak I have updated the answer with step 2 & 3.

Comment: Thanks for your code part, this is the right way. I tried your code but on the server side, when I `console.log(req.body);` for the target route, it's empty. And if I remove the "multiple" argument + the for loop on js, it display "{data:[Object...]}" I'm searching the solution.

Comment: @ceadreak I am using the same code and its successfully running on my local and server.

Comment: I found the solution, such I use Express 3.x framework, `Formidable` is included and each returned form is a `Formidable` form. To make it works with Express 3.x, just need to declare `var form = req.form` + add param `{defer:true}` on the bodyparser. Thanks again for your shared code.